# drop down on submit gives undefined - Angular4

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I had designed following form with use of ngModel banana-binding, on click of submit button I can get values for all control, except drop down control. Also I'm not able to give default select  option for all radio buttons used and it's same case with drop down control.

I had defined mediaModel as json object in typescript file and use it in ngModel to get all control's value on submit button.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem. As I'm very bad in UI designing, I am unable to find the root cause for this issue.

```html
<li>
      <div class="collapsible-header active">
        <b style="font-size: 15px;">Media Settings</b>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row ">
            <!-- <form class="col s12" [formGroup]="mediaSettingsForm" id="mediaSettingsForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitMediaSettings(mediaSettingsForm.value, mediaSettingsForm.valid)"> -->
            <!-- <form> -->

            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
              <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                <div class="form-group input-field">
                  <label>Disable Touch Screen</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                <div class="form-group input-field">
                  <input class="with-gap" name="disable_touch_screen" [(ngModel)]="mediaModel.disable_touch_screen" #disable_touch_screen="ngModel"
                    value="On" type="radio" id="disable_touch_screen_on" [checked]="checkFlag" />
                  <label for="disable_touch_screen_on">On</label>
                  <input class="with-gap" name="disable_touch_screen" [(ngModel)]="mediaModel.disable_touch_screen" #disable_touch_screen="ngModel"
                    value="Off" type="radio" id="disable_touch_screen_off" />
                  <label for="disable_touch_screen_off">Off</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row"></div>
              <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                <div class="form-group input-field">
                  <label>RTP Call Assurance</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                <div class="form-group input-field">
                  <input class="with-gap" name="rtp_call_assurance" [(ngModel)]="mediaModel.rtp_call_assurance" #rtp_call_assurance="ngModel"
                    value="On" type="radio" id="rtp_call_assurance_on" checked />
                  <label for="rtp_call_assurance_on">On</label>
                  <input class="with-gap" name="rtp_call_assurance" [(ngModel)]="mediaModel.rtp_call_assurance" #rtp_call_assurance="ngModel"
                    value="Off" type="radio" id="rtp_call_assurance_off" />
                  <label for="rtp_call_assurance_off">Off</label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                <div class="form-group input-field">
                  <label>Use Internal speaker/mic</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                <div class="form-group input-field">
                  <input class="with-gap" name="use_internal_speaker_mic" [(ngModel)]="mediaModel.use_internal_speaker_mic" #use_internal_speaker_mic="ngModel"
                    value="On" type="radio" id="use_internal_speaker_mic_on" checked />
                  <label for="use_internal_speaker_mic_on">On</label>
                  <input class="with-gap" name="use_internal_speaker_mic" [(ngModel)]="mediaModel.use_internal_speaker_mic" #use_internal_speaker_mic="ngModel"
                    value="Off" type="radio" id="use_internal_speaker_mic_off" />
                  <label for="use_internal_speaker_mic_off">Off</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                <div class="form-group input-field">
                  <!-- <select class="form-control browser-default" [(ngModel)]="mediaModel.device_type" style="display:block;">
                    <option value="default" disabled selected>Select Device</option>
                    <option value="ANDROID">Android</option>
                    <option value="IOS">iOS</option>                    
                  </select>      -->
                  <select class="form-control browser-default" style="display:block;" [(ngModel)]="mediaModel.device_type">
                    <option value="default" disabled selected>Select Device</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="ANDROID">Android</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="IOS">iOS</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default input-field color-blue" (click)="saveMediaSettings()">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Will you please check the answer? , Please upvote and accept the answer if it seems useful else please let me know I will remove.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with your code is `[ngValue]="ANDROID"`

Change `[ngValue]` to `ngValue` or `value` .

> Note :
>
> If you use [] with attribute then right side will be always a
>   expression ,
>
> So either you can use :
>
> `[attr]='expression'` or `attr='{{ expression }}'`
>
> But in your case its just simple string so you can use
>   `attr='your_value'`

**[For More Detail](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview)**

Answer (score 0):

let paste code in html section:

```
  <select class="form-control browser-default" style="display:block;"
                      [(ngModel)]="mediaModel.device_type">
                <option  disabled selected>Select Device</option>
                <option *ngFor="let eachDevice of devices" 
                [ngValue]="eachDevice.name">{{eachDevice.name}}</option>
   </select>
```

and also paste code in ts file

```
devices: any = [{name: 'Android'}, {name: 'IOS'}];
```